# Erase Alpha clarification needed

Tags: transparency, texture-painting, normal-map, bump, texture-paint-mode

I am new to Blender and texture paint my mesh. I have base color, color details and bump information images mixed in one material on one texture slot.
Bump information image has a normal map.

I need to eraser some information from bump image. When I do it with Eraser Alpha erased polygons turn into black. I cannot find any information in the Internet how I can erase only bump info and reveal base color and the details. Could you please help me to understand that? Thank you in advance!
Below attached my node editor.
[image]

Comment: Are you using eevee? If so, go to the material properties (right side) and scroll down until  you see _Blend Mode_ - make sure it is set to something other than _Opaque_

Comment: Yes, I'm using Eevee. My blend mode is Alpha blend

Comment: Erase alpha sets the alpha layer to 0 which makes that part of the texture invisible.

Comment: But how to make texture from other images (not the one I'm using Erase Alpha on) visible?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bburY.png <= just to clarify, do you want to make the model transparent at the black spot (=look through) or do you want to remove the bump data (=flat appearance)? The alpha slot of the *Principled BSDF* only affects the *Base Color* slot and makes the color transparent (you also need to set the *Blend Mode* to *Alpha Hashed* in the material settings.) If you want to get rid of the bumpiness then you need to paint the bump image with this grey color: HEX 808080. This is the "flat" value. Color values that are brighter create a bump and darker values create a dent.

Comment: I want only to remove bump data. I updated the image in the question. Set Alpha Hashed in the blend mode and switched the color to HEX 808080. There's still the issue

Comment: Have you created the bump image with an alpha channel? Maybe it's only a RGB image and that the reason why there is a black spot? Try to *Erase Alpha* on the black spot to remove it. Then paint with the 808080 color the bumps away. This should should as you see in the answer below.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation was very helpful. I found out that the reason was the brush I used for erasing. I used the one with added texture, when I switched to regular brush and  set Alpha Hashed mode and HEX 808080 bumpiness has gone away. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Erase Alpha* brush mode basically paints the alpha channel of an image black. *Add Alpha* paints it white. Black means the model is transparent at this spot. The image must have an *Alpha* channel (RGBA).

You can view the alpha channel if you connect it to an *Emission* node as show in the screenshot below. The *Node Wrangler* add-on can do this automatically for you with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+LMB.

[image: alpha mask]

If you set the *Blend Mode* in the material setting to *Alpha Hashed* you should see the hole in *Material Preview* and *Eevee* render mode. The render engine must be set to *Eevee* to see the setting.

If the setting is not correct the spot will not be transparent but shown as black.

[image: material preview]

With the *Add Alpha* brush mode you can fill the hole. In in *Image Editor* on the left you should see the transparency. The image must have an Alpha channel, of course.

[image: add alpha]

To remove the bumpiness of a bump map just paint the image with the grey color 808080 (HEX). Make sure the *Color Space* is set to *Non-Color*.
The image must not be transparent at that spot.

Brighter values up to pure white will create a bump while darker values will create a dent. Use the *Mix* brush mode.

[image: paint bump]